# Understanding the Difference between "Probability" and "Confidence"?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose there are 10 Experiments.  Each experiment is identical, but is performed on a slightly different dataset.

I observe the following:

- Experiment 1: Produces responses between 3.7 and 10.5
- Experiment 2: Produces responses between 4.7 and 13.2
- Experiment 3: Produces responses between 0.9 and 6.21
- Experiment 4: Produces responses between 3.1 and 5.6
- Experiment 5: Produces responses between 4.20 and 9.8
- Experiment 6: Produces responses between 1.7 and 2.1
- Experiment 7: Produces responses between 4.99 and 15
- Experiment 8: Produces responses between 4.99 and 10
- Experiment 9: Produces responses between 1 and 13.4
- Experiment 10: Produces responses between 3.7 and 16

As a factual statement, I could say that 9 out of these 10 Experiments produced results in the number "5" was produced. This means that if I could only select one of these experiments, I would have a 0.9 probability of picking an experiment that contains the number "5".

**This brings me to my question regarding the interpretation of probabilities in statistical experiments (e.g. confidence intervals).**

In applications of statistics within the real world, we tend to only have the ability to collect a single dataset and perform a single experiment. When we use the results of this experiment to estimate some parameter of interest (e.g. mean), we are often interested in placing a "confidence interval" on this estimate.

**In school, we are told again and again - "a 95% confidence interval DOES NOT mean that the true value of the parameter that you estimated lies within the 95% confidence interval based off of the data collection/experiment/estimation that you just performed"**.

Yet I have always struggled to understand why this is the case.

If you consider the example I provided:

- There is a 90% chance (i.e. 0.9 probability) of picking an experiment that contains the number "5"
- And obviously, if you pick this experiment - there is a 100% chance (i.e. a probability of 1) that this experiment contains the number "5"
- Therefore, in general, there is a 0.9 probability that any experiment chosen (i.e. performed) at random will satisfy this condition (i.e. contains the number "5")

**I am trying to understand why this analogy I presented does not apply to confidence intervals within statistical estimation.** I understand that the true parameter value might not be bounded from the 95% confidence interval created from the specific dataset you collected - but hypothetically, if you could repeat this data collection process many times  and repeat this experiment on each dataset: on average, in any one of these many datasets and many experiments, the true value of the parameter will be contained in the 95% confidence interval calculated using each of these datasets in general.

This being said - why are we then told that  "a 95% confidence interval DOES NOT mean that the true value of the parameter that you estimated lies within the 95% confidence interval based off of the data collection/experiment/estimation that you just performed"?

**Is this just a linguistics problem?**

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting confidence intervals. 95 CI means that if you were to repeatedly collect samples and construct a 95 CI for each sample, then approximately 95% of the intervals contains the population parameter. I have never heard anyone say what you say that we are repeatedly told in school.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to answer this:

- Let's say I performed some experiment and collected some sample data.
- I then fit some statistical model to this data (e.g. a classic regression model) and get the regression parameters (e.g. beta-1, beta-2, etc)
- I now calculate 90% confidence for these parameters
  e.g. beta-1 has a 90% confidence interval (e.g beta-1 plus/minus x1)
- It is wrong to conclude "there is a 0.9 probability that this confidence interval contains the true value of beta-1 (i.e. from the population)"
- But if you could collect sample data many times and perform the same experiment many times: 90% of the times, the original interval (plus/minus x1) would contain the true value of beta-1 (i.e. b1 from the population).

This being said, at the end of the day -  I have the same confusion as you : From the last bullet point - could someone indirectly argue that:

- 90% of the time - any randomly collected sample dataset, a model parameter of interest (e.g. beta-1) calculated from this dataset, and a 90% confidence interval placed on this model parameter of interest will contain the true value of this model parameter
- Consequently : 10% of the time - any randomly collected sample dataset, a model parameter of interest (e.g. beta-1) calculated from this dataset, and a 90% confidence interval placed on this model parameter of interest will NOT contain the true value of this model parameter
- Therefore,  there is a 0.9 probability that my specific dataset I collected is one of these datasets in which a confidence interval calculated on the model parameter will contain the true value
- And, therefore,  there is also a 0.1 probability that my specific dataset I collected is one of these datasets in which a confidence interval calculated on the model parameter will NOT contain the true value
- Thus - taking into account an infinite number of sample datasets that could have been collected in theory: there is a 0.9 probability that the 90% confidence interval contains calculated using my specific sample dataset WILL contain the true value of the model parameter

"Statistically" speaking, there is a very high "probability" that I am wrong about this!